# PL/SQL: Find all cyrillic (or non-latin1) signs via regex

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to output the IDs of all Rows within a table that contain any cyrillic (or non-latin-1) letters, no matter what column they're in
I've inherited a script that uses cursors to iterate through the tables and columns and searches for the cyrillic signs via a regex statement using unistr(), but i can't figure out why it does not seem to be working anymore on our oracle 12 db

The statement is as follows:

```
        stmt := 'select ID from '||table_name || ' where regexp_LIKE('||table_name||'.'||column_name||','||stmt_template|| ')';
```

table_name and column name should be selft explanatory, stmt_template is a template that is defined earlier and contains my problem. 'stmt' is used as follows (and works):

```
OPEN stmt_cursor for stmt;
    LOOP [some code]
```

The stmt_template is defined as follows and always throws me an error

`stmt_template VARCHAR(32767) := '^[''||unistr(''\20AC'')||unistr(''\1EF8'')||''-''||unistr(''\1EF9'')||unistr(''\1EF2'')||''-''||unistr(''\1EF3'')||unistr(''\1EE4'')||''-''||unistr(''\1EE5'')||unistr(''\1ED6'')||''-''||unistr(''\1ED7'')||unistr(''\1ECA'')||''-''||unistr(''\1ECF'')||unistr(''\1EC4'')||''-''||unistr(''\1EC5'')||unistr(''\1EBD'')||unistr(''\1EAA'')||''-''||unistr(''\1EAC'')||unistr(''\1EA0'')||''-''||unistr(''\1EA1'')||unistr(''\1E9E'')||unistr(''\1E9B'')||unistr(''\1E8C'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E93'')||unistr(''\1E80'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E85'')||unistr(''\1E6A'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E6B'')||unistr(''\1E60'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E63'')||unistr(''\1E56'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E57'')||unistr(''\1E44'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E45'')||unistr(''\1E40'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E41'')||unistr(''\1E30'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E31'')||unistr(''\1E24'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E27'')||unistr(''\1E1E'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E21'')||unistr(''\1E10'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E11'')||unistr(''\1E0A'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E0B'')||unistr(''\1E02'')||''-''||unistr(''\1E03'')||unistr(''\0292'')||unistr(''\0259'')||unistr(''\022A'')||''-''||unistr(''\0233'')||unistr(''\01FA'')||''-''||unistr(''\021F'')||unistr(''\01F7'')||unistr(''\01F4'')||''-''||unistr(''\01F5'')||unistr(''\01E2'')||''-''||unistr(''\01EF'')||unistr(''\01DE'')||''-''||unistr(''\01DF'')||unistr(''\01CD'')||''-''||unistr(''\01D4'')||unistr(''\01BF'')||unistr(''\01B7'')||unistr(''\01AF'')||''-''||unistr(''\01b0'')||unistr(''\01A0'')||''-''||unistr(''\01A1'')||unistr(''\018F'')||unistr(''\0187'')||''-''||unistr(''\0188'')||unistr(''\0134'')||''-''||unistr(''\017f'')||unistr(''\00AE'')||''-''||unistr(''\0131'')||unistr(''\00A1'')||''-''||unistr(''\00AC'')||unistr(''\0009'')||unistr(''\000A'')||unistr(''\000D'')||unistr(''\0020'')||''-''||unistr(''\007E'')||'']*$'')';`

This is supposed to be searching for a long list of cyrillic letters and other special characters, though it throws me the following:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I've already tried to search for everything not within the ascii table using

```
stmt_template VARCHAR(32767) :='''[^-~]''';
```

though this doesn't seem to give me the test-tuples I prepared (using some cyrillic characters as well as a € sign and stuff) but some rows that don't contain any 'illegal' characters

```
stmt_template VARCHAR(32767) := '''[^.' || CHR (1) || '-' || CHR (255) || ']''';
```

doesn't work either as it gives me the same as the above

can anyone help me identify my mistake/typo or whatever error there is in the first regex statement?

If you need any more information, please tell me, thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your statement evaluates to:

```
select ID from table_name where regexp_LIKE(table_name.column_name,,'^['||unistr('\20AC')||unistr('\1EF8')||'-'||unistr('\1EF9')||unistr('\1EF2')||'-'||unistr('\1EF3')||unistr('\1EE4')||'-'||unistr('\1EE5')||unistr('\1ED6')||'-'||unistr('\1ED7')||unistr('\1ECA')||'-'||unistr('\1ECF')||unistr('\1EC4')||'-'||unistr('\1EC5')||unistr('\1EBD')||unistr('\1EAA')||'-'||unistr('\1EAC')||unistr('\1EA0')||'-'||unistr('\1EA1')||unistr('\1E9E')||unistr('\1E9B')||unistr('\1E8C')||'-'||unistr('\1E93')||unistr('\1E80')||'-'||unistr('\1E85')||unistr('\1E6A')||'-'||unistr('\1E6B')||unistr('\1E60')||'-'||unistr('\1E63')||unistr('\1E56')||'-'||unistr('\1E57')||unistr('\1E44')||'-'||unistr('\1E45')||unistr('\1E40')||'-'||unistr('\1E41')||unistr('\1E30')||'-'||unistr('\1E31')||unistr('\1E24')||'-'||unistr('\1E27')||unistr('\1E1E')||'-'||unistr('\1E21')||unistr('\1E10')||'-'||unistr('\1E11')||unistr('\1E0A')||'-'||unistr('\1E0B')||unistr('\1E02')||'-'||unistr('\1E03')||unistr('\0292')||unistr('\0259')||unistr('\022A')||'-'||unistr('\0233')||unistr('\01FA')||'-'||unistr('\021F')||unistr('\01F7')||unistr('\01F4')||'-'||unistr('\01F5')||unistr('\01E2')||'-'||unistr('\01EF')||unistr('\01DE')||'-'||unistr('\01DF')||unistr('\01CD')||'-'||unistr('\01D4')||unistr('\01BF')||unistr('\01B7')||unistr('\01AF')||'-'||unistr('\01b0')||unistr('\01A0')||'-'||unistr('\01A1')||unistr('\018F')||unistr('\0187')||'-'||unistr('\0188')||unistr('\0134')||'-'||unistr('\017f')||unistr('\00AE')||'-'||unistr('\0131')||unistr('\00A1')||'-'||unistr('\00AC')||unistr('\0009')||unistr('\000A')||unistr('\000D')||unistr('\0020')||'-'||unistr('\007E')||']*$'))
```

Which, with the guts of the regular expression removed looks like:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(table_name.column_name,,'your regex...'))
```

You need to remove the duplicate comma from the start of the regular expression string and the duplicate closing round bracket from the end.

Comment: oh, thx, fixed that earlier actually, but afterwards it still gives me the same error, will edit the post!

Answer (score 0):

Change your definition of `stmt_template` to

```
stmt_template VARCHAR(32767) := '^[''''||unistr(''\20AC'')||unistr(''\1EF8'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1EF9'')||unistr(''\1EF2'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1EF3'')||unistr(''\1EE4'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1EE5'')||unistr(''\1ED6'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1ED7'')||unistr(''\1ECA'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1ECF'')||unistr(''\1EC4'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1EC5'')||unistr(''\1EBD'')||unistr(''\1EAA'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1EAC'')||unistr(''\1EA0'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1EA1'')||unistr(''\1E9E'')||unistr(''\1E9B'')||unistr(''\1E8C'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E93'')||unistr(''\1E80'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E85'')||unistr(''\1E6A'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E6B'')||unistr(''\1E60'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E63'')||unistr(''\1E56'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E57'')||unistr(''\1E44'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E45'')||unistr(''\1E40'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E41'')||unistr(''\1E30'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E31'')||unistr(''\1E24'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E27'')||unistr(''\1E1E'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E21'')||unistr(''\1E10'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E11'')||unistr(''\1E0A'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E0B'')||unistr(''\1E02'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\1E03'')||unistr(''\0292'')||unistr(''\0259'')||unistr(''\022A'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\0233'')||unistr(''\01FA'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\021F'')||unistr(''\01F7'')||unistr(''\01F4'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\01F5'')||unistr(''\01E2'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\01EF'')||unistr(''\01DE'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\01DF'')||unistr(''\01CD'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\01D4'')||unistr(''\01BF'')||unistr(''\01B7'')||unistr(''\01AF'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\01b0'')||unistr(''\01A0'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\01A1'')||unistr(''\018F'')||unistr(''\0187'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\0188'')||unistr(''\0134'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\017f'')||unistr(''\00AE'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\0131'')||unistr(''\00A1'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\00AC'')||unistr(''\0009'')||unistr(''\000A'')||unistr(''\000D'')||unistr(''\0020'')||''-''||
                                 unistr(''\007E'')||'''']*$'')';
```

It appears that the original definition left an unbalanced single-quote at the beginning and end of the string. I'm still not certain that will work as there appears to be an unmatched right-parenthesis at the very end of the string but it might be better.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you data that isn't within the ascii-7 range chr(32) - chr(127):

```
select col1
from my_table
where regexp_like(col1, '[^'||chr(32)||'-'||chr(127)||']')
```

Note that I'm excluding control characters (less than dec 32) and extended ascii (> 127) in my range.